# How to convert $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}$ to $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(\frac{a}{x})^2-(x-\frac{a}{2})^2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

When I was doing integral problems recently， I often see conversions like this.

such as:
$$\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}}= \int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a+b)x-x^2-ab}}}=\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{(a-b)^2}{4}-(x-\frac{a+b}{2})^2}}}$$

Is there any trick to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Completing the square, may be

Comment: Surely $(a/x)^2$ should be $(a/2)^2$.

Comment: You seem to have two separate questions here.  The title makes it sound like you are asking about an algebraic manipulation, and the body of the question makes it sound like you want help with a particular type of integral.  Can you edit your question to clarify the ambiguity?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{e^2 - (fx + g)^2}}$ will succumb to

$\displaystyle fx + g = e\sin t.$